# Cant access the NAS drive on network on Window 10 Non Admin Account

Tags: networking, nas, window

I have a NAS drive on my small office network that I am accessing from 6-7 desktop and laptops. The NAS drive has 6 folders, each exclusively accessed by one computer (using different username and passwords)

I bought a new desktop computer and connected it to the network (using ethernet cable).

Now from the admin account of this new computer I access the network location on NAS with dedicated user name and password. But when I try access the same network location from a second (non-admin) account of the same computer, it's giving me error. I'm the same username and password as used by the admin account of this computer to access the network folder.

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, I am using Window 10 Professional 64bit on a i5 8th Gen Desktop.

Here is the message popup for your reference:
[image: Popup message]

Comment: What version of SMB is your NAS using?  What operating systems are the working clients using?  Please update your question to include this vital information.

Comment: Check what `net use` is showing you. Do you actually log off as one user and login as the other or are you using the quick switch feature?

Comment: @Ramhound: How do I find it out? I am using a basic Western Digital 2 bay 4TB HDD. I used the web browser based UI to set it up. And it doesn't say any detail about which SMB/Linux running behind the scene.

Comment: @Seth: Thank you. I will check 'net use' when I go back to work. 
For older PCs I have logged on from the non admin account and saved the username and passwords and it's working fine. I don't have to add the username and password again and again to access to drives.

But, for this new PC I logged into the admin account and saved the NAS drive username and password and it's working fine from the admin account.
But when I use the second non admin account - it's asking for the username and pass and even though they are the same, it's not working, and I am getting the above popup (screenshot).

Comment: @saicode - You can answer what version SMB you are using, by answering my other question, "What operating are the working clients using".  Through the process of elimination, I can determine the answer myself if I have that information.

Comment: Please provide more information as mentioned by Ramhound in order to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Ramhound The problem got resolved on its own! after 2-3 days! Now I can access the NAS drive - not really sure how it got resolved because I had restarted the PC few times before posting the above comments...

Also, can't still find out the what SMB client it's running - I tried using Putty - but's refusing connection.